# How to update a container image running on ECS Fargate without killing existing long running websocket connections?

Tags: websocket, containers, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I have a WebSocket server running on ECS Fargate. The ws connections typically last from a few dozen minutes to a couple of hours. **How can I update the server code without killing existing connections?**

I though of launching the new code on a new task, then setting containers on the old task to DRAINING so that no new connections go to the old containers, then letting the container handle it's own termination, since it knows how many ws connections it has.

However, I can't find a way to set the state of a Fargate container. Only EC2 containers seem to be accessible/visible.

I also looked into setting the stop timeout to 2 days, but for Fargate, the limit is 2 minutes.